# Не удаётся стилизовать прогресс бар css

Tags: css, progress-bar

```css
.p::webkit-progress-bar {    background: red; }
```

```html
<progress class="p"> <progress/>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для начала, у вас не правильно закрыт тег `progress`, затем.. префикс пишется как `-webkit-`, не хватает тире в начале.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.p {
  accent-color: red;
}

/* или так */

progress {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

```html
<progress class="p"> </progress>
```

Можно попробовать через [`accent-color`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#widget-accent) если нужно поменять цвет самого ползунка

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно отключить дефолтное отображение прогесс-бара с помощью `-webkit-appearance: none;`, а уже потом задавать фон:

```css
.p { -webkit-appearance: none; }
.p::-webkit-progress-bar { background: red; }
```

```html
<progress class="p"> </progress>
```

Comment: Но теперь нет бегающего ползунка)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, а он и не будет бегающий - вариант стилизации вообще только один: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-bar

Comment: @OliverPatterson, но с помощью атрибутов `value=""` и `max=""` + немного магии js, думаю, можно сделать какое-то подобие "бегания" )